# Getting the value of session storage

Tags: javascript, html

This is a code on the product page x and the product id is 56

```
    sessionStorage.setItem("prodid", "%prodcode%");
```

I can call this product code on the y page using the code below

```
     alert(sessionStorage.getItem("prodid"));
```

Comment: I will get a alert of 56

But what i want is to get the value of the product code in view source so that i can pass it to third parties like Google analytics.

For example:

_gaq.push(['_addTrans',
    '56',           // product code
    'Acme Clothing',  // affiliation or store name
    '11.99',          // total - required
    '1.29',           // tax
    '5',              // shipping
    'San Jose',       // city
    'California',     // state or province
    'USA'             // country
  ]);

The above analytics code is just an example.

Comment: There's no way to do that. You could instead use the console: `console.log(sessionStorage.getItem("prodid"));` (F12 Developer Tools, Firebug, Chrome Console, etc.)...

Comment: If you want the value in the HTML just output `%prodcode%` again.

Comment: No, that doesn't works if i want to call the product code on an another page

Comment: You're probably thinking of something like echo which is found in some languages.  Javascript has `document.write()`, but I would advise creating a node that you can append it to as a text node instead.

Comment: Yes, you are correct but document.write actually writes it to frontend. But i wanted it get it displayed on the view source...

Comment: Also, if you need it visible only when you view the source of the document, use something like `document.write('<!--' + sessionStorage.getItem("prodid") + '-->')` but even then you can probably make a comment node via the DOM

Comment: Please restate your question providing all the requirements.  Your question is not clear enough.

Comment: You can pass the value to third party libraries without having it in the source directly: `_gaq.push(['_addTrans', sessionStorage.getItem("prodid"), ...]);`. Or do you mean something different?

Comment: Ohh, ok. Let me try it...

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two options here, depending on what you mean by "view source". If right-clicking and selecting "View source" is what you mean, then doing a `document.write` is your best option:

```
document.write('<!-- prodid: ' + sessionStorage.getItem('prodid') + ' -->');
```

If you have the ability to view the source in other ways, like using Firebug, Chrome developer tools, or the IE developer tools, then you can simply output the value in a hidden form field. This will not appear on the UI:

```
var prodIdElement = document.createElement('input');
prodIdElement.id = 'prodid';  // in case you want to target it in the DOM
prodIdElement.type = 'hidden';
prodIdElement.value = sessionStorage.getItem('prodid');

document.body.appendChild(prodIdElement);
```

You can then view the page's "rendered" source in the dev tool(s) of your choice, and you should see the newly added element at the bottom of the `body`.